# Proving that if $f\times f= f$, then $\exists A \subseteq \Bbb R: f = f_A$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

In an exercice I'm asked to prove the following:

> Let $f_A : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be defined as:
> $$f_A(x) = 0 \text{ if } x \notin A, \text{ and } f_A(x)=1 \text{ if } x \in A$$
>
> Then, Prove that, if $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a funcion satisfing: $f\times f= f$, then $\exists A \subseteq \Bbb R: f = f_A$.

This is how I tried to solve it:

If $f = 0$, then $f \times f = f$ and $f = f_\emptyset$.

If $f \neq 0$, then we can devide $f \times f = f$ by $f$ in both sides and get: $f = 1$. So we conclude that $f = f_\Bbb R$.

---

Is this correct? Because I think that I'm treating the function $f$ as a number and thus I'm restrictiong $f$ to only constant functions, but I'm not sure. Are there any other function such that $f \times f = f$ aside from $f = 0$ or $f = 1$ or did I get this right?

Comment: You cannot treat a function like a number. There could be non-zero functions that are *zero divisors*, i.e. functions $f, g$ both $\ne 0$ but $fg=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assuming that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ or $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. This is not correct. We may have $f(x)=0$ for some values $x$ and $f(x)=1$ for other values of $x$.

For a correct proof define $A$ as  $\{x: f(x)=1\}$. I leave it to you to verify that $f=f_A$ .

Answer (score 2):

If $f\times f = f$, i.e. $f(x)^2=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then it means that, for every $x\in\mathbb R$, we have $f(x)(f(x)-1)=0$, i.e. $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$. (It may be $0$ for some $x$ and $1$ for others.) Define $A$ as a set of those $x$ for which $f(x)=1$ and prove that $f=f_A$.